# Jquery $(this) selector

Tags: php, jquery

I am learning jQuery and I have this code :

```
 echo "<table border=1>                 
    <tr><th class='col1'>Mã Sinh Viên <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='$page' data-field='stuId' data-sort='$sort' data-key='$key'><img src='downArrow.gif'></a></th>
        <th class='col2'>Họ tên <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='$page' data-field='stuName' data-sort='$sort' data-key='$key'><img src='downArrow.gif'></a></th>
        <th class='col3'>Ngày sinh  <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='$page' data-field='stuDoB' data-sort='$sort' data-key='$key'><img src='downArrow.gif'></a></th>
        <th class='col4'>Giới tính <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='$page' data-field='stuSex' data-sort='$sort' data-key='$key'><img src='downArrow.gif'></a></th>
        <th class='col5'>Địa chỉ <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-page='$page' data-field='stuAdd' data-sort='$sort' data-key='$key'><img src='downArrow.gif'></a></th>
    </tr>
";
```

And some script :

```
$("#mainTable th a").click(function()   {
    var clicked= $(this);
    var page= clicked.data("page");
    var field= clicked.data("field");
    var sort= clicked.data("sort");
    var key= clicked.data("key");
    if(sort== 'up') {
        sort= 'down';
        clicked.html("<img src='downArrow.gif'>");
        clicked.attr("data-sort",sort);
    }
    else    { 
        sort= 'up';
        clicked.html("<img src='upArrow.gif'>");
    }
    showPage(page,field,sort,key);
});
```

What I need is when click on the image, it will change the picture. I used `.click` event and `$(this)` selector to handle element that was clicked. But when I click the picture it's still the same.

What's wrong with my code? I tried <kbd>CTRL-ALT-j</kbd> but there is no error. Please help me out.

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem with a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: We can't tell if `(sort == 'up')` evaluates to true without the actual text being present instead of `$sort` but I assume that's your issue

Comment: Have you assigned the `id` value `mainTable`  to your table...?

Comment: @I can ensure I have data-sort='up' at first time page load :D
I have a div id="mainTable" with table inside :D

Comment: your `<table>` should have the id="mainTable" or the selector should be `$('#mainTable table tr th a')` in this case

Comment: Is the event handler function being executed when you click a `th`? Put a `console.log` statement as the first line of the function to find out.

Comment: Does closing your images properly help?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `clicked.data("sort",sort);` to set `data-sort` attribute

```
$("#mainTable th a").click( function () { 
    var clicked = $(this);
    var page = clicked.data("page");
    var field = clicked.data("field");
    var sort = clicked.data("sort");
    var key = clicked.data("key");

    if (sort == 'up') {
        sort = 'down';
        clicked.html("<img src='downArrow.gif'>");
    } else {
        sort = 'up';
        clicked.html("<img src='upArrow.gif'>");       
    }
   clicked.data("sort",sort);
});
```

**[Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/kzwhn/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your table has no class.

In the javascript-code you select the table with class *mainTable*, but that table doesn't exist...

Comment: No I have a div id="mainTable" with table inside :D

Comment: Maybe you need to select the table too: `$("#mainTable table th a").click(function()   {`

Answer (score 0):

Try select anchor data by jQuery :

```
$("#mainTable th a").click(function()   {
    var clicked= $(this);
    var page= clicked.attr("data-page");
    var field= clicked.attr("data-field");
    var sort= clicked.attr("data-sort");
    var key= clicked.attr("data-key");
    if(sort== 'up') {
        sort= 'down';
        clicked.html("<img src='downArrow.gif'/>");
        clicked.attr("data-sort",sort);
    }
    else    { 
        sort= 'up';
        clicked.html("<img src='upArrow.gif'/>");
    }
    showPage(page,field,sort,key);
});
```